# AS3 button firing off multiple times if clicked fast only

Tags: actionscript-3

ok so, i wrote this code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;

stop();

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var defUrlReq = new URLRequest("indexCoontentLoad.swf");
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var myLoadedSwf:MovieClip = null;
var swfStage:Stage = this.stage;

/////////////// INITIATE LOADERS /////////////// 

loader.load(defUrlReq);

/////////////// START MAIN HANDLER FUNCTION ///////////////

/////IMPORT DEFAULT SWF /////
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, loadedHandler);
function loadedHandler(event:Event){  

    myLoadedSwf = event.target.content;
    addChild(myLoadedSwf);

    trace(myLoadedSwf);

    myLoadedSwf.gotoAndPlay("intro");
    trace("STEP 1 -- ext def swf loaded");
}
///////END IMPORT. ///////////////


///// START LISTENERS AND THEIR FUNCTIONS /////

load1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btn4Clicked);
load2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btn4Clicked);
load3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,btn4Clicked);

///// END LISTENERS /////


///// START FUNCTIONS /////

function btn4Clicked(e:MouseEvent):void { //-- START btn4Loaded
        if (e.target == load1 || e.target == load2 || e.target == load3) {
            myLoadedSwf.gotoAndPlay("outro");

            removeChild(myLoadedSwf);

            urlRequest = new URLRequest(e.target.name+".swf");
            loader.load(urlRequest);
            addChild(myLoadedSwf);
        }

}
```

and it works, once clicked, it does what it has to do. Ofcourse, me trying to break it, i found that if i click the buttons fast, it will re-import the external swfs causing me to have multiple instances of the external swf.

so in short, if i click like normal(slow ) ie like a person that clicked to view a section etc, then its fine, if i click fast or repeated clicking ie like a person that double clicks etc, then the problem occurs.

any ideas how to fix this?

thanks in advance.

edit*** heres a link to test file to show what i mean
http://www.somdowprod.net/4testing/flash/tst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set doubleClick to enabled on your movieclip, this will work. The Flash runtime will thencheck for you if it is a double click and only trigger your method once. If you want to listen for the double clicks, you can by changing the event handler.

```
mySprite.doubleClickEnabled = true;
mySprite.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
```

Good luck.

Comment: hello, thanks for your time. ook so i read the response above, and this one, i changed the code accordingly to compensate for the difference in function names etc,  and its still a no go. I edited my questions and posted the full code. Again, i copy/pasted your guys code, changed accordingly and the error i get is this: " Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 59 1119: Access of possibly undefined property clickCount through a reference with static type flash.events:Event.
 "

Comment: Change the type of the Event to MouseEvent. clickCount is a property of MouseEvent, so the error makes sense.

Edit: Changed this in your code.

Comment: yep thats what i did, i took the function name and changed it from " function btn4Loaded(e:Event) , to function btn4Loaded(e:MouseEvent), and i get this error :"1119: Access of possibly undefined property clickCount through a reference with static type flash.events:MouseEvent. ".

Comment: I changed my answer. Did a little test just now, and this should work.

Comment: hi. i solved it, had to use a crude method but w/e lol. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a boolean variable that is set to false. Once the .swf is loaded then change that variable to equal true. Then don't let the swf be loaded unless it is set to false. That way it'll only be allowed to be loaded once.

```
var isLoaded:Boolean = false;
function btn4Loaded(e:Event):void 
{ //-- START btn4Loaded
   if(!isLoaded)
   {
       if (e.target == load1 || e.target == load2) {
            myLoadedSwf.gotoAndPlay("outro");

            removeChild(myLoadedSwf);

            urlRequest = new URLRequest(e.target.name+".swf");
            loader.load(urlRequest);
            addChild(myLoadedSwf);
            isLoaded = false;
        }
    }

} // end btn4Loaded.
```